# std::function as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std-function

I currently have a `map<int, std::wstring>`, but for flexibility, I want to be able to assign a lambda expression, returning `std::wstring` as value in the map.

So I created this template class:

```
template <typename T>
class ValueOrFunction
{
private:
    std::function<T()> m_func;
public:
    ValueOrFunction() : m_func(std::function<T()>()) {}
    ValueOrFunction(std::function<T()> func) : m_func(func) {}
    T operator()() { return m_func(); }
    ValueOrFunction& operator= (const T& other)
    {
        m_func = [other]() -> T { return other; };
        return *this;
    }
};
```

and use it like:

```
typedef ValueOrFunction<std::wstring> ConfigurationValue;
std::map<int, ConfigurationValue> mymap;

mymap[123] = ConfigurationValue([]() -> std::wstring { return L"test"; });
mymap[124] = L"blablabla";
std::wcout << mymap[123]().c_str() << std::endl; // outputs "test"
std::wcout << mymap[124]().c_str() << std::endl; // outputs "blablabla"
```

Now, I don't want to use the constructor for wrapping the lambda, so I decided to add a second assignment operator, this time for the `std::function`:

```
ValueOrFunction& operator= (const std::function<T()>& other)
{
    m_func = other;
    return *this;
}
```

This is the point where the compiler starts complaining. The line `mymap[124] = L"blablabla";` suddenly results in this error:

> error C2593: 'operator = is ambiguous'

IntelliSense gives some more info:

> more than one operator "=" matches these operands: function
>   "ValueOrFunction::operator=(const std::function &other) [with
>   T=std::wstring]" function "ValueOrFunction::operator=(const T
>   &other) [with T=std::wstring]" operand types are: ConfigurationValue =
>   const wchar_t
>   [10]  c:\projects\beta\CppTest\CppTest\CppTest.cpp    37  13  CppTest

So, my question is, why isn't the compiler able to distinguish between `std::function<T()>` and `T`? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The basic problem is that `std::function` has a greedy implicit constructor that will attempt to convert *anything*, and only fail to compile in the body.  So if you want to overload with it, either no conversion to the alternative can be allowed, of you need to disable stuff that can convert to the alternative from calling the `std::function` overload.

The easiest technique would be tag dispatching.  Make an `operator=` that is greedy and set up for perfect forwarding, then manually dispatch to an `assign` method with a tag:

```
 template<typename U>
 void operator=(U&&u){
   assign(std::forward<U>(u), std::is_convertible<U, std::wstring>());
 }
 void assign(std::wstring, std::true_type /*assign_to_string*/);
 void assign(std::function<blah>, std::false_type /*assign_to_non_string*/);
```

basically we are doing manual overload resolution.

More advanced techniques: (probably not needed)

Another approach would be to limit the `std::function` `=` with SFINAE on the argument being invoked is valid, but that is messier.

If you have multiple different types competing with your `std::function` you have to sadly manually dispatch all of them.  The way to fix that is to test if your type `U` is callable with nothing and the result convertible to `T`, then tag dispatch on that.  Stick the non-`std::function` overloads in the alternative branch, and let usual more traditional overloading to occur for everything else.

There is a subtle difference in that a type convertible to both `std::wstring` and callable returning something convertible to `T` ends up being dispatched to different overloads than the original simple solution above, because the tests used are not actually mutually exclusive.  For full manual emulation of C++ overloading (corrected for `std::function`s stupidity) you need to make *that* case ambiguous!

The last advanced thing to do would be to use `auto` and trailing return types to improve the ability of other code to detect if your `=` is valid.  Personally, I would not do this before C++14 except under duress, unless I was writing some serious library code.

Comment: I was thinking on whether SFINAE would make sense, and I opted not to suggest it as overly complicated. Tag dispatch as exercised here is a good clean solution +1 (although it deserves more)

Answer (score 6):

Both `std::function` and `std::wstring` have conversion operators that could take the literal wide string you are passing. In both cases the conversions are user defined and thus the conversion sequence takes the same precedence, causing the ambiguity. This is the root cause of the error.