# C++ object keeps templated function and args as members to call later

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, std-function

I have a class `Door` that implements a method `LockCheck()`, and a class `Stove` with a method `BurnerCheck()`. I want a class `House` that takes as a constructor argument either `Door::LockCheck` or `Stove::BurnerCheck` along with an unknown set of args for the given function. `House` would then store the function and its args such that it can call them at some later time. For example,

```
auto stove = Stove();
auto stove_check = stove.BurnerCheck;
auto burner_args = std::make_tuple<bool, bool>(true, false);
auto house = House(burner_args, stove_check);
// do some other stuff...
house.check_safety();  // internally calls stove.BurnerCheck(burner_args)
```

What should class `House` "looks" like?

So far I have,

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
class House {

public:

    House(Args... args, std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> func)
        : input_args_(std::forward_as_tuple(args...)),
          safety_func_(func) {}
    };

private:

    Args... input_args_;  // Is this the correct declaration?
    std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> safety_func_;
};
```

Notes:

- C++11
- I've already seen related SO questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534812/how-does-the-template-parameter-of-stdfunction-work-implementation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612774/stdfunction-as-template-parameter).

Comment: I'd just do something like `House(std::function<void ()> func) : safety_func_(func) {}` with `std::function<void ()> safety_func_;` and use it as `auto house = House([]() { stove.BurnerCheck(true, false); });`.

Comment: @melpomene cool thanks, that's clean and concise. Followup question: Does a call to `house.check_safety()` that executes the private `safety_func_` callable reflect the state of `stove` at the time it was used to instantiate `house`, or does it reflect the current state of  `stove`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it takes a copy of `stove`. If you want it to use `stove` by reference, you need `[&]() { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some preliminary considerations.

1) If you write a template class `House`

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
class House {
  // ...

    House(Args... args, std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> func)
        : input_args_(std::forward_as_tuple(args...)),
          safety_func_(func) {}
```

where the argument of the check methods are "unknown" (and, I suppose, different from type to type) you have to know that arguments when you define the `House` objects and you have different `House` types (one `House` type for `Door`'s checks, one `House` type for `Stove`'s checks, etc.) and (before C++17) you can't declare `House` object simply as

```
auto house = House(burner_args, stove_check);
```

but you have to explicit the template types; something as

```
House<void, bool, bool> house{burner_args, stove_check};
```

Suggestion: in you are not interested in the `ReturnType` of the checks methods (and if you can ignore it) make `House` a not-template class and make a variadic template constructor for it; something as

```
class House
 {
   public:
      template <typename ... Args, typename F>
      House (Args ... as, F f)
```

2) If you have a template function/method/constructor with a some fixed arguments and a variadic list of arguments, place the variadic list of arguments in **last** position, so the compiler can deduce the variadic list of types from arguments and there is no need of explicit it.

So the preceding constructor become something as

```
  template <typename F, typename ... Args>
  House (F f, Args ... as)
```

3) As far I know, there is no way to pass a pointer to an actual method to a function o to a variable; so no

```
auto stove_check = stove.BurnerCheck;
```

and no `stove_check` as argument of `House` constructor.

The usual way that I know for this sort of problem is pass the object (`stove`) and a pointer to `BurnerCheck` method referred to the class, not to the object; something as

```
auto house { House(stove, &Stove::BurnerCheck, /* variadic args */) };
```

Now the contructor become

```
  template <typename T, typename M, typename ... Args>
  House (T t, M m, Args ... as)
```

and you can call the `BurnerCheck()` method of `stove` as

```
  (t.*m)(as...)
```

Now my suggested `House` class: a class with a `std::function<void(void)>` member that is initialized, in `House` constructor, with a lambda that capture object, pointer method and arguments.

And a `check_safety()` method that simply call that member.

Something as follows

```
class House
 {
   private:
      std::function<void(void)> fn;

   public:
      template <typename T, typename M, typename ... Args>
      House (T t, M m, Args ... as) : fn{[=]{ (t.*m)(as...); }}
       { }

      void check_safety ()
       { fn(); }
 };
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Door
 { void LockCheck (int, long) const { std::cout << "Door" << std::endl; } };

struct Stove
 { void BurnerCheck (char) const { std::cout << "Stove" << std::endl; } };

class House
 {
   private:
      std::function<void(void)> fn;

   public:
      template <typename T, typename M, typename ... Args>
      House (T t, M m, Args ... as) : fn{[=]{ (t.*m)(as...); }}
       { }

      void check_safety ()
       { fn(); }
 };

int main ()
 {
   auto stove { Stove{} };
   auto door { Door{} };
   auto house1 { House{stove, &Stove::BurnerCheck, 'a'} };
   auto house2 { House{door, &Door::LockCheck, 1, 2L} };

   std::cout << "Some other stuff" << std::endl;

   house1.check_safety();
   house2.check_safety();
 }
```

If you're interested in the value returned from the checked method... I suppose you can make `House` a template class with only the `ReturnType` parameter and adjust the class consequently.

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you for walking me through and helping my understanding!

Answer (score 1):

You can store all the arguments as a tuple. You can then call `safety_func_` by unpacking the tuple into function arguments. The unpacking can directly be done in C++17 using [std::apply](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply).

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
class House {
public:

    House(Args... args, std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> func)
        : input_args_(std::forward<Args>(args)...),
          safety_func_(func) {}

    // Require C++17
    ReturnType call_safety() {
        return std::apply(safety_func_, input_args_);
    }
private:

    std::tuple<Args...> input_args_;
    std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> safety_func_;
};
```

For a pure C++11 tuple unpacking solution, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)